# React: This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: reactjs

I Am Getting This Error Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it

And

Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Below picture is the index.ts code in the change-accouont folder in the pages folder. I want to open different pages here based on the parameters in the URL:
[image]

But when i enter the url, will show the below error.

Below is the DeleteAccountPage code:
[image]

Below picture is the createDeleteAccountPage code:
[image]

How to fix this error in react?

Comment: The error says it all, you are not returning a component in your function

Comment: Please post the code in code blocks rather than images.

Comment: check index.ts line 5

Answer (score 2):

if `DeleteAccountPage` and `ChangeAccountPage` are Component you need change your code to :

```
export default ()=>{
    if(retrieverUrlParamValue(changeTypeQueryParamNode)){
        return <DeleteAccountPage />;
    }else{
        return <ChangeAccountPage />;
    }
}
```

for return a component like DeleteAccountPage

```
return <DeleteAccountPage />
```

Comment: can you pulish your code on https://codesandbox.io ? it's help to find your issue

Comment: If I write the code: export default DeleteAccountPage, just export the single page. It's works. but If I use the if statement to judge display different pages, the error is reported.

Comment: I re-added the image to the question body

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything in your code blocks. You can do something like:

```
export default ()=>{
    if(retrieverUrlParamValue(changeTypeQueryParamNode)){
        return DeleteAccountPage;
    }else{
        return ChangeAccountPage;
    }
}
```

However you need to be careful how you use this code. Based on what you shared you'd need something like:

```
import AccountPage from 'the above file';

// Then in your render function
const conditionalComponent = AccountPage();
const FinalComponent = conditionalComponent(React.Fragment);
return <FinalComponent />;
```

This is arguably bad practice. Instead you should use component composition:

```
const DeleteAccountPage : FC<{ PageProvider: FC }> = ({ PageProvider }) => {
   return ( 
      <PageProvider>...</PageProvider>
   );
}

// ...

export default (props: { PageProvider: FC })=>{
    if(retrieverUrlParamValue(changeTypeQueryParamNode)){
        return <DeleteAccountPage {...props} />;
    }else{
        return <ChangeAccountPage {...props} />;
    }
}
```

This way to use this component you just need:

```
import AccountPage from 'the above index.ts file';

// ...
return <AccountPage PageProvider={React.Fragment} />
```